# how to properly @Autowire data access object outside of spring boot controller?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot app, which acts as a REST API, which receives JSON data, and persists it in a Postgres DB.
For that purpose, I have controllers, as well as a separate data access classes.
In my controllers, I'm using

```
 @Autowired
private CusttableDao custtableDao;
```

to auto-wire my DAO class, which looks like this:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CusttableDao {

    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CusttableDao.class);

    //EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "Eclipselink_JPA" );

  public void update(Custtable custtable) {
    entityManager.merge(custtable);
    return;
  }

  public Custtable getById(Class<Custtable> class1, CusttableCompositeKey custtableCompositeKey) {
        Custtable ct = entityManager.find(Custtable.class, custtableCompositeKey);
        return entityManager.find(Custtable.class, custtableCompositeKey);
    }

  public void create(Custtable custtable) {
        entityManager.persist(custtable);
        return;
      }

  public void delete(Custtable custtable) {
        if (entityManager.contains(custtable))
          entityManager.remove(custtable);
        else
          entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(custtable));
        return;
      }

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

For the purposes of REST API service, this arrangement works well.

Recently, I've been asked to add a capability to receive data from Kafka.

For this purpose, I have constructed a ThreadPool and a Consumer classes:

```
@Component
public class ConsumerThreadPool {

    private static final String TOPIC = "test5";
    private static final Integer NUM_THREADS = 1;

    @Autowired
    private ConsumerConfigFactory consumerConfigFactory;

    private ConsumerConnector consumer;
    private ExecutorService threadPool;

    public ConsumerThreadPool() {
        threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void startConsuming() {
        ConsumerConfig consumerConfig = consumerConfigFactory.getConsumerConfig();
        consumer = createJavaConsumerConnector(consumerConfig);

        consume();
    }

    public void consume() {
        Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        topicCountMap.put(TOPIC, NUM_THREADS);
        Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
        List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(TOPIC);

        int threadNumber = 0;
        for (final KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream : streams) {
            threadPool.submit(new ErpConsumer(stream, threadNumber));
            threadNumber++;
        }
    }


public class ErpConsumer implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    private CusttableDao custtableDao;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> kafkaStream;
    private int threadNumber;

    public ErpConsumer(KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> kafkaStream, int threadNumber) {
        this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
        this.kafkaStream = kafkaStream;
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = kafkaStream.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            byte[] messageData = it.next().message();
            try {
                String msg = new String(messageData);

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(msg);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {                  
                    JSONObject custtableObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);                  
                      dispatchRecord(custtableObject);
                        }  
                System.out.print(msg + "\n");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

        System.out.println("Shutting down Thread: " + kafkaStream);
    }

    private void dispatchRecord(JSONObject record) throws JSONException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
        String changeTableName = record.getString("upk_changedtablename");
        record.remove("upk_Accountnum");

        switch (changeTableName) {
            case "Custtable":  
                Custtable custTable = mapper.readValue(record.toString(), new TypeReference<Custtable>(){});

                custTable.setPartition( Long.valueOf(record.getString("upk_partition")).longValue());

                Long  keyfieldrecid = custTable.getUpk_keyfieldrecid();
                Long partition = custTable.getUpk_partition();

                if(custTable.getOptype().equals("U")) {

                    Custtable customer = (Custtable) custtableDao.getById(Custtable.class, 
                            new CusttableCompositeKey 
                            (custTable.getUpk_keyfieldrecid(),custTable.getUpk_partition())); 

                BeanUtils.copyProperties(custTable, customer);

                customer.setCusttableCompositeKey(new CusttableCompositeKey 
                        (keyfieldrecid,partition));

                custtableDao.update(customer);
                   }

            default: 
                     break;
            }   
    }
```

Unlike it was with the Rest Controller, using

```
@Autowired
    private CusttableDao custtableDao;
```

does not help - the custtableDao remains null here:

```
Custtable customer = (Custtable) custtableDao.getById(Custtable.class, 
                            new CusttableCompositeKey 
                            (custTable.getUpk_keyfieldrecid(),custTable.getUpk_partition()));
```

What is the proper way for me to auto-wite/instanciate/access my DAO in my Consumer, which is not of type RestController?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ErpConsumer` class is not a managed bean you are instantiating it yourself in this line:

```
threadPool.submit(new ErpConsumer(stream, threadNumber));
```

`@Autowired` only works for beans that are managed by Spring.

Instead inject your dao to your `ConsumerThreadPool` which is a managed bean (because of the `@Component` annotation). Then add the dao as a parameter in the constructor of  `ErpConsumer` and create instances of it this way:

```
threadPool.submit(new ErpConsumer(custtableDao,stream, threadNumber));
```

Here's how your constructor might look like:

```
public ErpConsumer(CusttableDao custtableDao,KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> kafkaStream, int threadNumber) {
        this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
        this.kafkaStream = kafkaStream;
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        this.custtableDao = custtableDao;
    }
```